# Adding a new column in a data frame using a formula that combines entries from other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame "Values" with entries as follows:

```
     Test1 Test2 Test3 


Power1 20 30 40

Power2 10 15 13

Max_Power1 30 50 90

Max_Power2 50 80 40

Voltage1 1.2 1.2 1.2

Voltage2 1.3 1.3 1.3

Current1 1.0 1.2 1.3

Current2 2.0 2.1 2.2
```

I need to create a new column that will contain the following:

- Average value of row 1
- Average value of row 2
- Max value of row 3
- Max value of row 4
- Average value of row 5
- Average value of row 6
- Min value of row 7
- Min value of row 8

Short of creating this as a separate data frame with one column, setting each row entry individually and then importing into original data frame I do not know of a way to do this with a single commmand.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: There's not a single command to do this oddly specific operation. Just get it done one item at a time.

Comment: Your structure here is not a `data.frame`; if it is, then it is incorrectly made that way, as what you depict and describe is either a `matrix`, a transposed `data.frame`, or something else entirely. Adding your summary statistics is certainly possible but in my opinion is not really "tidy data". Is there a reason you want to co-mingle data and summary statistics in the same matrix/frame?

Comment: Very percertive r2evans. Yes, it is a transpose of a data frame. Let me explain. I have 5 csv files, each file has columns named Voltage1, Voltage2, etc, Current1, Current2, etc and then Power1, Power2, etc. Each column has 900k entries. I read the data and find the average of each column, and also the maximum for the Power columns and min for the Current columns. This initial data frame is 40 columns wide and only 5 rows in length. I then transpose and stored it as a CSV file so I can display it in Excel. Unfortunately, I do additional post-processing and would rather do it in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `test` given in the Note at the end create a vector of function names, `fun`, and `mapply` the each function to the the corresponding row:

```
avg <- mean
fun <- c("avg", "avg", "max", "max", "avg", "avg", "min", "min")
n <- nrow(test)
rows <- split(as.matrix(test), 1:n)
transform(test, Value = mapply(function(fun, x) match.fun(fun)(x), fun, rows), Stat = fun)
```

giving:

```
           Test1 Test2 Test3    Value Stat
Power1      20.0  30.0  40.0 30.00000  avg
Power2      10.0  15.0  13.0 12.66667  avg
Max_Power1  30.0  50.0  90.0 90.00000  max
Max_Power2  50.0  80.0  40.0 80.00000  max
Voltage1     1.2   1.2   1.2  1.20000  avg
Voltage2     1.3   1.3   1.3  1.30000  avg
Current1     1.0   1.2   1.3  1.00000  min
Current2     2.0   2.1   2.2  2.00000  min
```

Perhaps another possibility is to simply calculate the min, mean and max of every row.

```
stats <- function(x) c(Min = min(x), Avg = mean(x), Max = max(x))
cbind(test, t(apply(test, 1, stats)))
```

giving:

```
           Test1 Test2 Test3  Min       Avg  Max
Power1      20.0  30.0  40.0 20.0 30.000000 40.0
Power2      10.0  15.0  13.0 10.0 12.666667 15.0
Max_Power1  30.0  50.0  90.0 30.0 56.666667 90.0
Max_Power2  50.0  80.0  40.0 40.0 56.666667 80.0
Voltage1     1.2   1.2   1.2  1.2  1.200000  1.2
Voltage2     1.3   1.3   1.3  1.3  1.300000  1.3
Current1     1.0   1.2   1.3  1.0  1.166667  1.3
Current2     2.0   2.1   2.2  2.0  2.100000  2.2
```

### Note

We assume that `test` is:

```
test <- structure(list(Test1 = c(20, 10, 30, 50, 1.2, 1.3, 1, 2), 
Test2 = c(30, 15, 50, 80, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 2.1), Test3 = c(40, 13, 90, 40, 1.2, 
1.3, 1.3, 2.2)), .Names = c("Test1", "Test2", "Test3"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Power1", 
"Power2", "Max_Power1", "Max_Power2", "Voltage1", "Voltage2", "Current1", "Current2"))
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. Can you please explain where the value of "x" comes from?

Comment: `x` is an argument to the anonymous function.

Comment: Very elegant solution. Much better than the single row approach I was using, which works but it is very crude. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The anomaly in this question is that we need to calculate some statistics that aren't typically calculated on rows. There are a number of ways to solve this problem.

First, we could use the `rpgm` package and its `rowMins()` and `rowMaxs()` functions to augment `base:rowMeans()`. Note that we want to only calculate on columns 2 - 4, because the Measurement column is not numeric.

```
rawData <- "Measurement  Test1 Test2 Test3 
Power1 20 30 40
Power2 10 15 13
Max_Power1 30 50 90
Max_Power2 50 80 40
Voltage1 1.2 1.2 1.2
Voltage2 1.3 1.3 1.3
Current1 1.0 1.2 1.3
Current2 2.0 2.1 2.2"

data <- read.table(text=rawData,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# use rpgm package
library(rpgm)
rowMaxs(data[3:4,2:4])
rowMeans(data[c(1:2,5:6),2:4])
rowMins(data[7:8,2:4])
```

...and the output:

```
> library(rpgm)
> rowMaxs(data[3:4,2:4])
[1] 90 80
> rowMeans(data[c(1:2,5:6),2:4])
       1        2        5        6 
30.00000 12.66667  1.20000  1.30000 
> rowMins(data[7:8,2:4])
[1] 1 2
```

Another alternative is to reshape the data using the `reshape2` package so we can calculate the statistics on columns rather than rows.

```
library(reshape2)
data <- read.table(text=rawData,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data2 <- melt(data,id=c("Measurement"))
data3 <- dcast(data2,variable ~ Measurement)
colMeans(data3[,6:9])
colMins(data3[,2:3])
colMaxs(data3[,4:5])
```

...and the output:

```
> library(reshape2)
> data <- read.table(text=rawData,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> data2 <- melt(data,id=c("Measurement"))
> data3 <- dcast(data2,variable ~ Measurement)
> colMeans(data3[,6:9])
  Power1   Power2 Voltage1 Voltage2 
30.00000 12.66667  1.20000  1.30000 
> colMins(data3[,2:3])
[1] 1 2
> colMaxs(data3[,4:5])
[1] 90 80
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The reshape2 idea is something i didn't consider when writing my code, it seems fairly simple to do that, calculate the statistics I need and then transpose to my final format.

Comment: @DarthRatus - you're welcome. Please accept the answer if you found it to be helpful.